# Followability gem on Ruby on Rails mutual_following_with? method problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using this gem for followability: https://github.com/nejdetkadir/followability

every other method works but when I try to unfollow I get this error:

```
uninitialized constant Followability::Followable::Relationship
Did you mean?
Followability::Relationship
```

this line is highlighted on the error:

```
 @user.unfollow(current_user) if @user.mutual_following_with?(current_user)
```

related code and lines I tried (in profile.controller.rb):

```
  def make_it_a_unfriend_request
        #@user.unfollow(current_user) if current_user.mutual_following_with?(@user)
        @user.unfollow(current_user) if @user.mutual_following_with?(current_user)
  end
```

```
 def unfollow
    make_it_a_unfriend_request

    current_user.unfollow(@user)
    redirect_to profile_path(@user)

  end
```

how can I fix this, is this a problem with the gem?

Comment: It looks like you just need a more recent version of the gem. This pull request seems to be a resolution for your issue: https://github.com/nejdetkadir/followability/pull/13. You can bundle from Github directly using the `git` option for this gem in your Gemfile https://bundler.io/guides/git.html

Comment: i'm not sure how to do it if it's not too much work can you show me how to do please

Comment: nevermind got it. sorry im a noob and thank you lol